# android visibility of software keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to check if the software keyboard is visible. I have read this  [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android).

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
            ... do something here
        }
     }
});
```

but `activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight()` and `activityRootView.getHeight()` always returns the same value, does not care if the keyboard is visible or not. Any ideas why? Because it seems that this solution works for others.

Comment: Did you add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" into your AndroidManifest?

Comment: It solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code might help -

```
public void dismissKeyboard(){
    InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mSearchBox.getWindowToken(), 0);
    mKeyboardStatus = false;
}

public void showKeyboard(){
    InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    mKeyboardStatus = true;
}

private boolean isKeyboardActive(){
    return mKeyboardStatus;
}
```

The default primative boolean value for mKeyboardStatus will be initialized to false.

Then check the value as follows, and perform an action if necessary:

```
mSearchBox.requestFocus();
if(!isKeyboardActive()){
    showKeyboard();
}else{
    dismissKeyboard();
}
```

**EDIT -**

The simplest method to find out -

```
contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
 public void onGlobalLayout() {

Rect r = new Rect();
contentView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
int screenHeight = contentView.getRootView().getHeight();

// r.bottom is the position above soft keypad or device button.
// if keypad is shown, the r.bottom is smaller than that before.
int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

Log.d(TAG, "keypadHeight = " + keypadHeight);

if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.20) { // 0.20 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
    // keyboard is opened
}
else {
    // keyboard is closed
}
}
});
```

Like this answer? Mark this as `selected` please :).

Comment: Thanks for solution and It's working fine. why use 0.20 ratio is used?